# shaky political ground

Tags: meaning-in-context

what is the meaning of this sentence:

"This is shaky political ground and what appears to be dogged cultural relativism can infuriate scientists. Unfortunately, their own track record isn’t too persuasive."

in this context:

A Navaho sand painting ritual for a sick child is a mystery – we literally cannot read the signs nor subscribe to the belief, let alone the science, that she can be made better this way. Are we then to dismiss this cultural practice? This is shaky political ground and what appears to be dogged cultural relativism can infuriate scientists. Unfortunately, their own track record isn’t too persuasive.

Does it mean :

"shaky political ground and dogged cultural relativism can infuriate scientists. Unfortunately, scientists do not represent a persuasive past in their activity."

Answer (score 1):

The question whether or not to dismiss the practices is *shaky political ground*.

That implies that it is "politically correct" *not* to dismiss the practices.

However, *not* dismissing it (because we do not understand it) appear to be cultural relativism.

This kind of cultural relativism is something that can infuriate scientists.

However, scientists themselves do not have a good track record.

What track record is referred to is a bit hazy. Either the author implies scientists have been bad at curing sick children, or scientists have dismissed too many things that they didn't understand.

<sub>Note that I am trying to explain what the author meant, and that this does not represent my own opinion.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

**on shaky ground** is a metaphor for building a structure on unstable land: it is at risk of falling down

From http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/on+shaky+ground:

> [of an idea or proposal] on an unstable or questionable foundation;
>   [of an idea or proposal] founded on a risky premise.

So, in the context the phrase means the subject (trying to cure a child with sand paintings) is politically risky: to say "don't do it, it won't work" seems to be denying a sick child a chance (however infinitely remote), which comes across as closed minded (rejecting their beliefs) and heartless, to say "do do it" seems to be buying in to the mysticism, which of course a scientist shouldn't really be giving credence to (for their reputation if nothing else).

Answer (score 1):

The shaky political ground refers to this: People who ascribe to mainstream western medical theory do not think that sand paintings can heal a person. These people might have a desire to stop the Navajo from painting in the sand and impose what modern culture sees as more valuable medical practices. While this is motivated out of a desire to save more lives, and thus is an understandable desire, it also would eradicate part of the Navajo culture and is a form of cultural conquest or destruction. Therefore, it's a controversial issue, with potential pros and cons.

The scientists here are those who strongly believe in mainstream western medicine, and they are infuriated, according to the author, by the valuing of a cultural practice above practices which the scientists think would save human lives. The second sentence refers to how modern western medicine has a dubious history, and has harmed many people. The author is claiming that the scientists' desire to impose modern medicine on the Navajo is, to some degree, illegitimate, because, in the eyes of the author, modern medicine is no better than the Navajo medicine.

This is a topic that can inspire heated argument, and I have tried to be even-handed in my answer.